# Cold atoms: how does evaporative cooling work?

Tags: atomic-physics, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

I understand the principle of evaporative cooling (for the creation of a Bose-Einstein Condensate), but I do not find any reference which explains mathematically this process and which explains what minimal temperature one can reach. Can someone describe mathematically how evaporative cooling works?

Comment: @HotLicks How is that relevant to evaporative cooling of atomic clouds in the context of the creation of BECs?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooling_(atomic_physics)) on atomic-physics evaporative cooling is pretty thin on the details, but its [main reference](https://doi-org.recursos.biblioteca.upc.edu/10.1016/S1049-250X(08)60101-9) looks pretty relevant. For a readable but complete treatment, my first guess for a good place to go would be the PhD theses of the students at the Cornell and Keterle groups at the time that they were first creating BECs.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you, but apparently I can't load the main reference since I am not living in the right country. I'll just continue digging around but it seems every reference available on the internet about this subject is a bit thin !

Comment: @Physicsman Ah, apologies, I left my library's proxy address in. The paper is [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1049-250X(08)60101-9); it's paywalled, but a preprint is [here](http://www.rle.mit.edu/cua_pub/ketterle_group/Projects_1996/Pubs_96/kett96_evap_preprint.pdf).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you ! It seems that I will find answers :) have a good day !